# HTML table design issues

Tags: html, html-table

Hi I am trying to create a table with html tags for my requirement but couldn't be able get when I tried.
My requirement is below.

[image]

What I am able to get is 
[image]

Is it possible to get this using html table tags. Kindly help me pls

Comment: use colspan rowspan attributes. its not complicated. here example:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan

Comment: post whatever you have now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, with `colspan` and `rowspan` see example below.

With `colspan` you can merge multiple row into one section

> ## colspan
>
> This attribute contains a non-negative integer value that indicates for how many columns the cell extends. Its default value is 1. Values higher than 1000 will be considered as incorrect and will be set to the default value (1).

With `rowspan` you can merge col into one.

> ## rowspan
>
> This attribute contains a non-negative integer value that indicates for how many rows the cell extends. Its default value is 1; if its value is set to 0, it extends until the end of the table section (`<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`, even if implicitly defined, that the cell belongs to. Values higher than 65534 are clipped down to 65534.
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="11">Northern District</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Maria Anders</td>
    <td colspan="3">Germany</td>
    <td colspan="3">Maria Anders</td>
    <td colspan="3">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro</td>
    <td>Francisco</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <td>Centro</td>
    <td>Francisco</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <td>Centro</td>
    <td>Francisco</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks mate @Daniel. It is perfectly suited for my req. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Search for the HTML attributes `colspan` and `rowspan` for `td` elements - that's what you need in this situation.

(for example here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp )

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <th colspan=11>Northern District
<tr>
 <td rowspan=2>Customers
 <td rowspan=2>Salesman
 <td colspan=3>Gas
 <td colspan=3>Diesel
 <td colspan=3>Total
<tr>
 <td>Volume
 <td>Netback
 <td>Profit
 <td>Volume
 <td>Netback
 <td>Profit
 <td>Volume
 <td>Netback
 <td>Profit
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. This helps